# Android alarm fails to start

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to set an alarm to a given time of the day, to work some logic at that time. Here is my code for this end:

```
 //Create alarm manager
 AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

 //Create pending intent & register it to your alarm notifier class
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

 //set timer you want alarm to work
 Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();
 timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, myHour);
 timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE, myMinutes);
 timeOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

 //set that timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
 alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

AlarmReceiver is an inner class located in the same class that runes this code. Here is AlarmReceiver's definiton:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(BackgroundSensorService.this, "ALARM TRIGGERED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why is the toast not showing. It seems that AlarmReceiver never gets any intents, and therefor never runs.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Clone the calendar instance and use it for setting the alarm.

Comment: Make sure the AlarmReceiver is declared in your manifest.